# Duplicating an object but when you move it. it distorts

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine

blender community

I am struggling with a problem of when I duplicate an object that has an animation and an armature when I move it to another location using X, Y, Z axis it distorts...
[image]

Duplicating...
[image]
Annoying distortion...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be the following one:

If you duplicate an object that has an armature, you should also duplicate the armature, otherwise it will still be influenced by the original armature, because by default it is still parented to it.

On the center of my picture, my original object + armature. On the left, copied with the armature, it's not influenced anymore by the original armature but by the copied one. On the right, copied without the armature, it's still parented to the original armature.

So you need either to copy object + armature or to unparent.

[image]